# How to calculate maximum similarity between synsets in NLTK? -Python

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, wordnet

I have to calculate the synset similarity between items of list1 and list2. I want to keep only the maximum synset similarity value for a word in list1. How do I do this? I want my output to be

```
apple.n.01, pear.n.01: 0.909090909091
honey.n.01, pear.n.01: 0.333333333333
```

Mycode

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet
>>> import itertools as IT
>>> list1 = ["apple", "honey"]
>>> list2 = ["pear", "shell", "movie", "fire", "tree", "candle"]
>>> for word1, word2 in IT.product(list1, list2):
    wordFromList1 = wordnet.synsets(word1)[0]
    wordFromList2 = wordnet.synsets(word2)[0]
    s = wordFromList1.wup_similarity(wordFromList2)
    print('{w1}, {w2}: {s}'.format(w1 = wordFromList1.name,w2 = wordFromList2.name,s = wordFromList1.wup_similarity(wordFromList2)))


apple.n.01, pear.n.01: 0.909090909091
apple.n.01, shell.n.01: 0.4
apple.n.01, movie.n.01: 0.421052631579
apple.n.01, fire.n.01: 0.142857142857
apple.n.01, tree.n.01: 0.380952380952
apple.n.01, candle.n.01: 0.380952380952
honey.n.01, pear.n.01: 0.333333333333
honey.n.01, shell.n.01: 0.210526315789
honey.n.01, movie.n.01: 0.222222222222
honey.n.01, fire.n.01: 0.125
honey.n.01, tree.n.01: 0.2
honey.n.01, candle.n.01: 0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
import itertools as IT
list1 = ["apple", "honey"]
list2 = ["pear", "shell", "movie", "fire", "tree", "candle"]
def f(word1, word2):
    wordFromList1 = wordnet.synsets(word1)[0]
    wordFromList2 = wordnet.synsets(word2)[0]
    s = wordFromList1.wup_similarity(wordFromList2)
    return(wordFromList1.name, wordFromList2.name, wordFromList1.wup_similarity(wordFromList2))

for word1 in list1:
    similarities=(f(word1,word2) for word2 in list2)
    print(max(similarities, key=lambda x: x[2]))
```

It creates a generator that returns the words and their similarities. The tuple with the largest value in its 3rd element is then printed.